# How to automate Xcode 4 to do Find & Replace (using both textual and regex styles)?

Tags: iphone, xcode, xcode4, applescript

I am trying to use AppleScript to automate manual Find & Replace, but with no luck.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no straightforward way to do this. Scripting in Xcode 4 is less robust than many of us would wish. You can do it with GUI scripting. Here's a sample script to set the find and replace text and then clicks the "replace all" button. Obviously you'll want to modify this for your own uses but it illustrates the principles.

```
tell application "Xcode"
    activate
end tell

tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Xcode"
        keystroke "f" using {command down, option down}
        set value of text field 1 of group 1 of splitter group 1 of group 2 of splitter group 1 of group 1 of front window to "<string>"
        set value of text field 2 of group 1 of splitter group 1 of group 2 of splitter group 1 of group 1 of front window to "<string2>"
        click button "Replace All" of group 1 of splitter group 1 of group 2 of splitter group 1 of group 1 of front window

    end tell
end tell
```